# What causes a linux server to send BPDU

Tags: linux, networking

We have Linux servers setup to host Mysql databases as VMWare guests.

Recently we started seeing spanguardlock locking port due to linux servers sending a `BPDU`.

What can cause a linux server to start sending BPDU and how can we stop this?

**UPDATE**

I have discovered having `lldpad` package installed will cause `lldpad daemon` to send `BPDU` on server startup.

I have disabled that on my CentOS server and don't seem to get it but Ubuntu still sends this.

So there must be some other service causing `BPDU` being send from servers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server probably has a bridge with [STP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_Tree_Protocol) enabled. Disabling STP on the bridge will stop the BPDUs from being sent. For Linux bridges this can be done with `brctl stp br0 off`; I'm not sure about VMware.

Answer (score 1):

Whyever the BPDUs are sent: If you have VMs then you probably have bridge interfaces and (rather as a workaround than a solution) on these you can drop the BPDUs with ebtables.

Answer (score 0):

As the name implies BPDU (Bridge Protocol Data Units) are the PDU's used by network connections that are "bridged" together.

Do you have multiple NICs on this server or is this server perhaps virtualized and you have the NIC's bridged?  Is it possible that you have a "loop" somewhere in your network and that the switches are sending BPDU guard packets to try to percent them from happening?

Would you mind posting the results of an 'ifconfig' from the server experiencing the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: I have just eth0 ethernet and local loopback lo